# Can two different classes inherit same base?

Tags: ios, class

Ok, If I subclass a class it inherits all methods and properties that class has but imagine I have a bunch of code and properties and I want that to be common to two different classes, is that possible by inheritance?

For example suppose a UIViewController and a UITableViewController.

Comment: have you considered creating a protocol for a base class and implement it on the two classes you want to have similarities?

Comment: yes, two different classes can be inherited from the same base-class. opposite to one class can be inherited only one parent in _Obj-C_ or _Swift_. you may play with conforming same protocols but that is not inheritance purely.

Comment: can I have the protocol method's implementation on the protocol .h?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question the answer is no. You can have as many classes as you want inherit from the same class, but you can’t have a class inherit from two classes. What might work for you is to create a singleton class. I have a Utilities class that I use for common operations like finding the mid-point of the screen, removing files from the cache, copying files, etc. It has 20 or so methods that I use in several different classes. I have another singleton class I use for setting and getting global variables like system version, fonts, text size, player name, etc.

I call the utility methods like this:

```
        NSString *resultsFilePath          = [Utilities cachedFilePath:@"Results"];
        NSString *fullResultsFilePath      = [Utilities cachedFilePath:@"FullResults"];
        NSString *troublesomeWordsFilePath = [Utilities cachedFilePath:@"TroublesomeTargets"];

       [Utilities copyCachedResultsToFile];
```

And Global variables like this:

```
if ([Globals sharedInstance].currentClient) {
        self.clientInput.text = [Globals sharedInstance].currentClient;
    }
```

My Utilities class starts like this:

```
//
//  Utilities.m
//
//  Created by John Scarry on 11/3/11.
//  Copyright (c) 2011 Learning Fundamentals, Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Utilities.h"
#import "mach/mach.h"

@implementation Utilities

+ (CGPoint)findMidpoint:(UIView *)view {
    CGPoint midPoint;
    midPoint.x = view.bounds.origin.x + view.bounds.size.width/2;
    midPoint.y = view.bounds.origin.y + view.bounds.size.height/2;
    return midPoint;
}

+ (NSString *)formattedDate {
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSString *todaysDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    return todaysDate;
}

+ (NSString *)formattedClientName {
    NSString *client = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" "]; 
    if( [Globals sharedInstance].currentClient ) client = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ",[Globals sharedInstance].currentClient];
    return client;
}
```

And my Globals class starts like this:

```
//
//  Globals.m
//
//  Created by John Scarry on 11/3/11.
//  Copyright (c) 2011 Learning Fundamentals, Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Globals.h"

@implementation Globals

static Globals *singleton = nil;

+(Globals *) sharedInstance {

    if (nil != singleton) return singleton;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;        // lock
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{             // this code is called at most once
        singleton = [[Globals alloc] init];
    });

    return singleton;

}

// Lots of the properties use a default value from the .pch file
// Use lazy instantiation to overide the getter to make sure it is set.

- (NSInteger) systemVersionNumber {

    return [[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."][0] intValue];
}

- (NSString *)scoringType {

    if ( !_scoringType ) _scoringType = SCORING_TYPE;
    return _scoringType;
}

- (NSString *)targetSoundDelayCode {

    if ( !_targetSoundDelayCode ) _targetSoundDelayCode = TARGET_SOUND_DELAY;
    return _targetSoundDelayCode;
}

- (BOOL)checkBoxes {

    if ( !_checkBoxes ) _checkBoxes = FORCED_CHOICE_SCORING;
    return _checkBoxes;
}

- (BOOL)showFavorites {

    if ( ! _showFavorites ) _showFavorites = NO;
    return _showFavorites;
}
```

Edit: I use a .pch for each app that sets defaults for lots of my globals. e.g.

```
#define FORCED_CHOICE_SCORING NO
#define SCORING_TYPE @"CDI"
```

Then I write a custom getter that uses the default value if the user hasn’t changed it.

```
- (NSUInteger)targetSoundDelay {

    if ( !_targetSoundDelay ) _targetSoundDelay = TARGET_SOUND_DELAY];
    return _targetSoundDelay;
}

- (NSString *)scoringType {

    if ( !_scoringType ) _scoringType = SCORING_TYPE;
    return _scoringType;
}
```

Comment: There's no need to create 'Utilities' classes in Objective-C -- just use C functions to implement functionality that's completely global. Use class methods for class-specific behavior. Also, consider using the `registerDefaults:` method of `NSUserDefaults` for global values such as the ones you're managing in your `Globals` class.

Comment: @jlehr I use NSUserDefaults to save user-selected options, but in my case I have 28 apps that use the same project code. For me, it’s a lot easier to manage the defaults by using a global .pch file and one for each app.

Comment: @jlehr Using C functions seems interesting. Can you point me to some examples?

Comment: You may find it even easier -- not to mention more flexible -- to share defaults by externalizing them to a plist file. Your app can then read the plist at launch time, using the resulting dictionary to initialize the `NSUserDefaults` registration domain (`NSRegistrationDomain`). The registration domain is separate from the application domain used to store user preferences, and is never persisted.

Comment: @JScarry wrote: "Can you point me to some examples?" Sure, just look at the Foundations Functions reference, which documents common C functions such as `NSLog`, `NSAssert`, and `NSLocalizedString`. Or for that matter, the UIKit Functions reference.